# What is this plastic tubing and why would water be dripping from it?

Tags: plumbing

I heard dripping in my furnace room and found this thin plastic tubing coming from under the overhead insulation.

It is dripping slowly but steadily, and appears to be clean water, **I.E.** No smell or discoloration.

Thoughts, Before I go tearing it apart?

[image]

Comment: Is the tubing connected to anything on either end? My first thought is that it could be a furnace condensate line, does it connect to the furnace?

Comment: Looks like a supply line for a reverse osmosis water purifier. Do you have one? But it shouldn't be dripping unless it has a leak and needs repair. Is the drip from where it's tapped into the copper water supply line?

Comment: "condensate" was my first thought too. But it *looks* like it is attached to the copper pipes - e.g., a supply line for a refrigerator ice maker. **Where is the dripping?**

Comment: it may be used to keep the floor drain trap from drying out

Answer (score 4):

It looks to be a saddle valve which is used often because it means that you can add a tap for a fridge's ice maker to an existing water line without cutting into them. However they can start to leak and they don't get a perfect seal into the pipe when turned off either.

If you find it leaking you should be able to replace it with a proper tee and valve to fix the leak.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to what does it do lies above the floor where it appears to go through.  Ice maker/refrigerator supply line, water filter line, etc.  Could be many things.

But the point is that is SHOULD NOT BE LEAKING!  Your photo doesn't show any leaks but these "saddle" taps are notorious for leaking.  They have a rubber washer that hardens and cracks over time and allows leaks to start.

The tube should also not be leaking but it may be old and deteriorated.  If there are any junctions in it, they should be checked.

Answer (score 2):

Since the "question" is

> "*Thoughts, Before I go tearing it apart?*"

My thoughts are.

**1st**, Determine what the water  tubing is supplying water to, *we can not tell you that.*

**2nd**, Determine where the leak is coming from BEFORE you tear it apart, otherwise you will not know what needs to be repaired.

Once you know where the leak is coming from you will have a better idea of how to fix it or what question to ask us.

Comment: 3rd. Turn the water off at the main and drain the lines before you go tearing it apart. Open hot water faucets upstairs as you do this....